# How to verify the private key I have matches AWS keypair?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh-keygen

My AWS instance says it is configured to use the only keypair I have on my account and it has a fingerprint in the format of:

3c:64:a7:85:53:3f:81:1c:24:5a:d2:6a:5b:76:47:da:f3:14:63:88

I have a key.pem file on my computer. **How do I verify that this pem file matches up with the above key-pair fingerprint provided by AWS?**

I have attempted the following:
ssh-keygen -lf key.pem

That outputs something in this format:
2048 SHA256:TpL6i8y1uCd26IUVVc5UHFluP7GLKD/T3O1+K4Pc0qg no comment (RSA)

The encoding scheme is different, I am not able to tell if they are equivalent.

I am trying to debug why I am unable to ssh into my instance with this key, this is the first step I am trying.

Comment: Try logging into an instance with the certificate

Comment: Hey Tim, like I mentioned, I am unable to ssh into the instance. Unless you mean something different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two methods, depending on how you created your SSH key as described in [Verifying Your Key Pair's Fingerprint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#verify-key-pair-fingerprints) in AWS docs.

Here is my SSH key fingerprint in the console:

[image: EC2 Key Pairs Screenshot]

And here is how to get the same fingerprint from the command line:

```
~ $ openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/aws-sandpit.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl md5 -c
writing RSA key
(stdin)= ae:ae:56:84:f9:72:c4:d1:0a:b8:e9:3b:ab:d4:a7:00
```

If that doesn't match try this:

```
~ $ openssl pkcs8 -in path_to_private_key -inform PEM -outform DER -topk8 -nocrypt | openssl sha1 -c
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That second option is what worked for me for a PEM-formatted private key generated by AWS just today.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, `ssh-keygen` displayed fingerprints using a hex-encoded MD5 hash. More recently, OpenSSH added support for -- and changed the default to -- base64-encoded SHA-256.

You can add the option "`-E md5`" to use the old format, though it will now be prefixed with "`MD5:`".

```
$ ssh-keygen -lf id_ed25519
256 SHA256:4gU2OwTypjq8lE6CvwTUZYQ6gyRRqXvKsZt1yUAGC2s mnordhoff@jane (ED25519)

$ ssh-keygen -lf id_ed25519 -E md5
256 MD5:41:e3:9f:30:a7:92:66:70:18:18:7d:e7:cd:66:ba:1d mnordhoff@jane (ED25519)
```

Comment: Unfortunately such a fingerprint doesn't match the AWS one. Apparently they use the algorithm as described in the accepted answer.